# Sulla differenza fra 'nulla' e 'qualcosa' in 'non c'è alcun presupposto per sperare nulla/qualcosa'

Tags: grammar

Ho detto ad uno:

> Sorry, non c'è alcun presupposto per sperare nulla.

È corretto?

O avrei dovuto dire

> Sorry, non c'è alcun presupposto per sperare qualcosa.

?

Cioè, qual è la differenza fra dire 'nulla' e dire 'qualcosa' qui?

Answer (score 2):

The first expression:

> Sorry, non c'è alcun presupposto per sperare nulla

is incorrect, as it has a triple negation (*non*, alcun = *nessun* and *nulla*).

An appropriate version (though rather old-fashioned) could be:

> Non c'è alcun presupposto per sperare alcunché

Note how "alcuno" maps nicely to "alcunché".

This is a guide to consider the other phrase ("...sperare qualcosa").  While it is not incorrect (double negation!), it does not sound equally good, because of a sort of clash between alcuno and qualcuno.

On the other hand, to make things even more complicated, it is correct to say:

> Non c'è nessun presupposto per sperare qualcosa

And the latter possibly sounds the best of all of the above.

Comment: How is *alcunché* different from *nulla* in this case? [Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/alcunche/) states that they are equivalent in negative sentences.

Comment: Alcunche belongs to the family of "pronomi indefiniti singolativi" which indicate a person or a single thing in an imprecised way. Nulla belongs to the "pronomi indefiniti negativi" which negate something completely. See http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronomi-indefiniti_(La_grammatica_italiana)/

Comment: Se la domanda è scritta in italiano dovresti rispondere in italiano. Se è scritta in inglese dovresti rispondere in inglese. Mescolare le lingue significa minimizzare la possibilità che l'OP comprenda la risposta; in altri termini rendi la tua risposta meno utile.

Comment: La frase 1 non è una tripla negazione: "alcuno" non ha valenza negativa. Si usa in frasi negative esattamente come "any" in Inglese "not...any". La frase 1 è neppure una doppia negazione, perché il linguaggio corrente usa "nessuno" e "nulla" in senso indefinito al posto di alcuno/alcuna cosa/alcunché ("non ho visto nessuno", che non è una doppia negazione).

Answer (score 0):

Le due frasi sono entrambe corrette, con una differenza di significato.

Nella prima il risultato atteso è *nullo*; nella seconda è *scarso* o insufficiente. In generale nelle frasi negative "qualcosa" al posto di "alcuno" vale "di qualche entità o rilevanza".